# Expected value of the points one can get in a game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Our game is the following: we are given 10 boxes with 1 ball, 15 boxes with 2 balls,
20 boxes with 3 balls, and 5 boxes with no ball. We open a box, if the number of balls
is odd, we get 5 points. Otherwise, we loose 2 points. What is the expected value of
the points one can get in a game?
Here's what I've tried: suppose that X is a function that assigns -2 and 5 values based on the number of balls in the box, so I multipled -2 by 10/50, then by 20/50, and I multipled 5 by 15/50 and 5/50 and summed that all up, which I think will give me the expected value. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: There's a lot of excess information here.  There are $10+20=30$ odd boxes, and $15+5=20$ even ones, making $50$ boxes all in all.  With probability $\frac {30}{50}=\frac 35$ you win $5$ and with probability $\frac {20}{50}=\frac 25$ you lose $2$, so your expected P&L is $\frac 35\times 5-\frac 25\times 2 =\frac {15}{5}-\frac 4{5}=\frac {11}{5}$.